# How can I do unit testing of a method which is making retrofit call inside of AndroidViewModel class?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, retrofit2, android-viewmodel

I want to write a unit test for a method which is performing signUp by making a retrofit call, and that method is inside a AndroidViewModel class.How can I test this method?

```
public class SignUpViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final Context context;
    private LoadToast loadToast;

    public SignUpViewModel(@NonNull Application application, Context context) {
        super(application);
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void signUpRequest(final String userName, String userPassword, String userEmail, String firstName, String lastName, String securityQuestion, String securityAnswer) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject securityJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        loadToast = new LoadToast(context);
        loadToast.setText("Signing in");
        loadToast.show();
        try {

            jsonObject.put("identifier", userName);
            jsonObject.put("password", userPassword);
            jsonObject.put("email", userEmail);
            jsonObject.put("firstName", firstName);
            jsonObject.put("lastName", lastName);
            securityJsonObject.put("question", securityQuestion);
            securityJsonObject.put("answer", securityAnswer);
            jsonObject.put("securityQuestion",securityJsonObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        APIService apiService = RetrofitClient.getAPIService();
        Call<String> signUpResponse = apiService.createUser(jsonObject.toString());
        signUpResponse.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.message().equals("timeout")) {
                    loadToast.error();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Network Connection issues please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    loadToast.success();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "An activation link has been sent to your email. Follow it to activate your account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LogInActivity.class));
                } else if (response.code() == 409) {
                    loadToast.error();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "User With Same UserName already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    loadToast.error();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Something went wrong please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                loadToast.error();
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }


}
```

My class looks something like this and I want to test `signUpRequest` method. I read some tutorials but they aren't helping. So, how can I write unit test to test my methods?

Comment: You need to inject your retrofit dependencies in your `SignUpViewModel` constructor so you can mock its result and be able to unit test it

Comment: I am new to unit testing and I am learning it, is there any example that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to Clean architecture approach your ViewModel code have not to contain any Framework related code. Especially context. All this work what you do with retrofit have to be moved in another layer. Move this code in UseCase or Interactor and use Repository pattern. This link may be helpful: https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-clean-architecture-on-android-2e5e8c8e81fe

Good architecture will make your code testable.
Hope it'll help :)